# DegradedArray event after removing raid with mdadm

Tags: ubuntu, raid, software-raid, mdadm

My new server (ubuntu22) from hetzner has 2 ssds and and an additional big hdd that is intended to be used for back-ups only. Initially 3 raids were preinstalled, and the biggest part of an hdd was unaccessible. I don't know why, but one raid included all 3 disks. I removed it from hdd, created just a single 100% /dev/sda1 and started getting mdadm errors like:

```
A DegradedArray event had been detected on md device /dev/md/1.

Faithfully yours, etc.

P.S. The /proc/mdstat file currently contains the following:

Personalities : [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid10]
md1 : active raid1 nvme0n1p2[0] nvme1n1p2[1]
      1046528 blocks super 1.2 [3/2] [UU_]

md0 : inactive nvme0n1p1[0](S) nvme1n1p1[1](S)
      67041280 blocks super 1.2

md2 : active raid5 nvme0n1p3[0] nvme1n1p3[1]
      930740224 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/2] [UU_]
      bitmap: 4/4 pages [16KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

I guess md0  was for rescue file system, but I'm not sure. I removed it with `mdadm --remove /dev/md0`, but errors are still there. Now the message is:

```
A DegradedArray event had been detected on md device /dev/md/1.

Faithfully yours, etc.

P.S. The /proc/mdstat file currently contains the following:

Personalities : [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid10]
md1 : active raid1 nvme0n1p2[0] nvme1n1p2[1]
      1046528 blocks super 1.2 [3/2] [UU_]

md2 : active raid5 nvme0n1p3[0] nvme1n1p3[1]
      930740224 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/2] [UU_]
      bitmap: 4/4 pages [16KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

Some more outputs:

```
> lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
loop0         7:0    0  44.5M  1 loop  /snap/certbot/2344
loop1         7:1    0   114M  1 loop  /snap/core/13425
loop2         7:2    0    62M  1 loop  /snap/core20/1611
loop3         7:3    0  63.2M  1 loop  /snap/core20/1623
sda           8:0    0   5.5T  0 disk  
└─sda1        8:1    0   5.5T  0 part  /home/backup
nvme0n1     259:0    0 476.9G  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1 259:2    0    32G  0 part  
├─nvme0n1p2 259:3    0     1G  0 part  
│ └─md1       9:1    0  1022M  0 raid1 /boot
└─nvme0n1p3 259:4    0 443.9G  0 part  
  └─md2       9:2    0 887.6G  0 raid5 /
nvme1n1     259:1    0 476.9G  0 disk  
├─nvme1n1p1 259:5    0    32G  0 part  
├─nvme1n1p2 259:6    0     1G  0 part  
│ └─md1       9:1    0  1022M  0 raid1 /boot
└─nvme1n1p3 259:7    0 443.9G  0 part  
  └─md2       9:2    0 887.6G  0 raid5 /




> blkid
/dev/nvme0n1p3: UUID="826df9bd-accd-335f-14a1-2069a029de70" UUID_SUB="96648f8a-eaeb-28fb-d481-4106d12b8637" LABEL="rescue:2" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="5b5edee1-03"
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="39a665ea-06f0-8360-a3d8-831610b52ca2" UUID_SUB="6bcef918-3006-6d2b-aeb8-0fa8973b86e1" LABEL="rescue:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="5b5edee1-01"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="b21423c4-a32f-b69b-5e42-6a413783d500" UUID_SUB="c77a1e86-e842-2d92-e8af-10ae88dc4c15" LABEL="rescue:1" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="5b5edee1-02"
/dev/md2: UUID="bd7e9969-8af6-49ae-b9a6-3ff7269bb962" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/nvme1n1p2: UUID="b21423c4-a32f-b69b-5e42-6a413783d500" UUID_SUB="52caf216-b553-cbfc-e7f8-50986a235537" LABEL="rescue:1" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="a69e312f-02"
/dev/nvme1n1p3: UUID="826df9bd-accd-335f-14a1-2069a029de70" UUID_SUB="72a04ab2-d87a-1c45-fbfb-556c3b93e758" LABEL="rescue:2" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="a69e312f-03"
/dev/nvme1n1p1: UUID="39a665ea-06f0-8360-a3d8-831610b52ca2" UUID_SUB="628713c9-8f69-e186-bbb8-ad352005c449" LABEL="rescue:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="a69e312f-01"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="datapartition" UUID="9b1b12b1-fcff-43b0-a2d2-d5e147f634c0" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="a0de21cb-c74d-4aed-a6ed-2216c6a0ec5b"
/dev/md1: UUID="2f598097-fad2-4ee5-8e6f-e86a293730bb" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext3"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"




> fdisk -l
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 476.94 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk model: SAMSUNG MZVLB512HBJQ-00000              
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x5b5edee1

Device         Boot    Start        End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1          2048   67110911  67108864    32G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/nvme0n1p2      67110912   69208063   2097152     1G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/nvme0n1p3      69208064 1000213167 931005104 443.9G fd Linux raid autodetect


Disk /dev/nvme1n1: 476.94 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk model: SAMSUNG MZVLB512HBJQ-00000              
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xa69e312f

Device         Boot    Start        End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/nvme1n1p1          2048   67110911  67108864    32G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/nvme1n1p2      67110912   69208063   2097152     1G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/nvme1n1p3      69208064 1000213167 931005104 443.9G fd Linux raid autodetect


Disk /dev/sda: 5.46 TiB, 6001175126016 bytes, 11721045168 sectors
Disk model: HGST HUS726060AL
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 297D9FC7-CD48-4610-802B-ED8D6DF3DC2A

Device     Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1   2048 11721043967 11721041920  5.5T Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/md2: 887.62 GiB, 953077989376 bytes, 1861480448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 524288 bytes / 1048576 bytes


Disk /dev/md1: 1022 MiB, 1071644672 bytes, 2093056 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes




> cat /proc/mdstat
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root

# definitions of existing MD arrays
ARRAY /dev/md/0  metadata=1.2 UUID=39a665ea:06f08360:a3d88316:10b52ca2 name=rescue:0
ARRAY /dev/md/1  metadata=1.2 UUID=b21423c4:a32fb69b:5e426a41:3783d500 name=rescue:1
ARRAY /dev/md/2  metadata=1.2 UUID=826df9bd:accd335f:14a12069:a029de70 name=rescue:2

# This configuration was auto-generated on Wed, 07 Sep 2022 21:20:22 +0200 by mkconf
root@mail:/home/logs# cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid10] 
md1 : active raid1 nvme0n1p2[0] nvme1n1p2[1]
      1046528 blocks super 1.2 [3/2] [UU_]
      
md2 : active raid5 nvme0n1p3[0] nvme1n1p3[1]
      930740224 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/2] [UU_]
      bitmap: 4/4 pages [16KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>




> mdadm --detail /dev/md1
/dev/md1:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Wed Sep  7 22:19:42 2022
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 1046528 (1022.00 MiB 1071.64 MB)
     Used Dev Size : 1046528 (1022.00 MiB 1071.64 MB)
      Raid Devices : 3
     Total Devices : 2
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Sun Sep 11 14:37:34 2022
             State : clean, degraded 
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 2
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : resync

              Name : rescue:1
              UUID : b21423c4:a32fb69b:5e426a41:3783d500
            Events : 182

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0     259        3        0      active sync   /dev/nvme0n1p2
       1     259        6        1      active sync   /dev/nvme1n1p2
       -       0        0        2      removed





> mdadm --detail /dev/md2
/dev/md2:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Wed Sep  7 22:19:42 2022
        Raid Level : raid5
        Array Size : 930740224 (887.62 GiB 953.08 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 465370112 (443.81 GiB 476.54 GB)
      Raid Devices : 3
     Total Devices : 2
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Mon Sep 12 00:31:56 2022
             State : clean, degraded 
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 2
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 512K

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              Name : rescue:2
              UUID : 826df9bd:accd335f:14a12069:a029de70
            Events : 373931

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0     259        4        0      active sync   /dev/nvme0n1p3
       1     259        7        1      active sync   /dev/nvme1n1p3
       -       0        0        2      removed
```

I guess something is not fully removed, and I'm asking for help to understand what's going on.

Comment: `md1` is *partially* degraded, it is `UU_` (where `U` corresponds to the active device and `_` stands for the missing one). `md2` seems to be worse: it is *fully* degraded — it's RAID5 where one device is missing, so there is a real risk for losing its data. For further help, please [attach](https://serverfault.com/posts/1110439/edit) `mdadm --detail /dev/md1` and `mdadm --detail /dev/md2` to the question. Also explain the intended end state: what do you think it should be?

Comment: The question updated with `--detail`. I'm probably not smart enough to understand the benefits of RAID5 especially when the disks are different. I wanted just a single RAID1 for 2 equal ssd-s + hdd separately without any raid. Do you think it's possible to fix the case without reformatting everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `md1`

Essentially, your `/dev/md1` is fine. It is RAID1 (mirror) configured to have three copies of the data, but you only have two copies. That's a degraded by definition, but the data is protected from the death of any single device. If you don't need to have three copies, you can just reconfigure the system for it to know two copies is enough:

```
mdadm --grow /dev/md1 -n2
```

This will release the state and `mdadm --detail /dev/md1` should show "Optimal".

### `md2`

The situation is worse. `/dev/md2` is three device RAID5 with one device missing. It is degraded and if any more device dies, your data are lost. Or you can think of it at if it was RAID0 — essentially it is like that currently. If you don't have third device and don't plan to install it, you may go for RAID1. There are caveats, however.

The first is that the **available space will be half of what it is now**. If more than a half of a file system is used, that data won't fit on RAID1 built from those devices. So before you begin, ensure that your data would fit on a single device (this would be the available space for the RAID1 case).

The second is that, unfortunately, I'm afraid there is no reasonably safe way to convert it to RAID1 on the fly. While some conversions between RAID levels are possible, I'd rather not play games with degraded RAID5. There will be some downtime, and you need some place to temporary store the data.

So your plan would be to copy the contents somewhere on to the spare storage, remove md2 altogether and create new RAID1 from its former components, then copy the contents back to that array. This is Linux, there is no requirements on copying method other than it should fully retain all permissions and extended attributes. Since this is root file system, you will need to boot it from some bootable external media, for instance, ubuntu live will do (or gparted).

Also, when everything is in place, you'll probably need to adjust the initramfs to account for the new array, while still being boot from the removable media (it is needed for Debian, from which Ubuntu descends, so I presume the requirement still applies). You need to update `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` file in the root file system and then recreate initramfs for it to include the updated file.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I restored the raids back using `mdadm --add /dev/md2 /dev/sda1` and now it looks like my raids are fixed, no more DegradedArray. Your explanation is definitely the answer.

Comment: I think this is very inefficient configuration. You are mixing NVME and some SCSI-protocol devices (I don't know what your sda is, but based on the fact it is at least 5.5T, it couldn't be as fast as NVME). in a single array. Your RAID consumes two NVME devices, but works as slower device.

Comment: Yes, and there's one more question back. Where's my 5TB HDD?:) That was the reason I started playing with raids. Right now there's <1TB of available storage on /dev/md2 (which is raid5 [UUU]). And that's fine, I don't need more space in the / partition. But it seems only a small part of HDD is in use.

Comment: Your sda1 was mounted as /home/backup some time ago (that's gone, it couldn't be mounted like that anymore - previous content is already irreversibly destroyed). Where it is? You've added it into array.

Comment: The content is destroyed, and this is fine, I have not started doing anything on this HDD anyway. It looks like that hetzner's default configuration has an issue. It makes raid5 that works as slow as hdd and has the size of ssd.

Comment: OK, you are free to fix that. For instance, you shouldn't add HDD into NVME array.

Comment: That's what I was trying to do and did it completely wrong by just removing hdd from the raid (I did not know raid5 requires 3 disks). One possible way is how you described it in the aswer. It's probably possible to remove HDD from md2 first, move all the data there, then load from rescue, destroy md2 and create raid1 instead on ssds only, then move the content back and hope it will load. It sounds quite risky overall.

Comment: I think you did the correct first step. Instead of returning the disk into RAID, you could copy the contents to the disk, recreate the RAID and copy it back, as I described in the answer. You still can do that from the Hetzner emergency environment.

Comment: I would like to thank you one more time, your diagnosis was very correct and solution worked quite well. I removed HDD from the array, copied the data there, then loaded rescue, replaced broken raid5 with new raid1 and now have everything working.